# Controlling access to methods

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to control access to methods to certain roles in .net. Like

```
class A
{
    //should only be called by Admins**
    public void Method1() { }

    //should only be called by Admins and PM's** 
    public void Method2() { }
}
```

I'm using windows authentication only for retrieving user names and nothing more.User roles are maintained in a different application. I think it's possible through attributes but I'm not really sure how

Comment: No; it is not possible through attributes.  What so you want to happen if the method is called while running as a different user? Where do you want to put the validation?

Comment: You _could_ succeed with Aspect Orientated Programming (AOP) and [something like PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/authorization).

Comment: "No; it is not possible through attributes." ???? What about PrincipalPermissionAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
class A 
{     
    //should only be called by Admins**     
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Admin")] 
    public void Method1() 
    { 
    }      

    //should only be called by Admins and PM's**      
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Admin")] 
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="PM")] 
    public void Method2() 
    { 
    } 
}
```

To do this `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` must be set to a principal that has the required roles.  For example, if you enable `roleManager` in an ASP.NET application, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` will be set to a `RolePrincipal` with roles from your configured RoleProvider.  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200.aspx) for more info.

Comment: This is what I was reffering too, but put much better

Answer (score 3):

It it possible, I have used it on an web project that used asp.net and AzMan as the authentication.

Take a look at [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

From memory all of our methods looked something like

```
[Permission(SecurityAction.Demand, "Permission")]
public void Method1
```

It's been a while though so that might not be actually 100% correct.

I'd also highly suggest if you are going to put protection down to this level to look at a [task orientated permission approach](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/) as this is much more flexible than role based permissions

Comment: I do think he is _not_ refering to Windows users/groups.

Comment: My answer doesn't refer to windows users/groups does it

Comment: Yes, I do think it does. What, other than a Windows group should your "UserRole" be?

Comment: You just jogged my memory we did it permission based, but there were still "Roles" they essentially were just ways of grouping permissions, nothing here essentially tied it to windows though

Comment: see Joes answer that was what I was trying to suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using custom validation.

1- Make a method in another public class which take login id as parameter and return roles in form  of bits.

2- Call this method on the page_Load event of the required class and save returned bits in the view state.

3- Now validate required method on the basis of roles bits.